# How to force heatmap probability levels to all be plotted on the same scale.

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use R to plot spatial heat maps on the same probability scale. So far I have been trying to use scale_alpha_continuous() function to force this, however it doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
  heat %>% ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  stat_density_2d(geom = "raster", aes(fill = stat(density)), contour = FALSE)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=matlab.like(15), na.value = "gray")+
  geom_point(size=0.1, color="red")+
  scale_alpha_continuous(limits=0,2.5e-6)
```

Comment: You're not using/specifying `alpha` in any of the `aes`. Maybe you wanted to do this: `aes(fill = stat(density), alpha = density)`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried to implement this change and it resulted in no plotting. I am also not trying to change the tranparency or anything, but rather scale the density so that all of my heatmaps show the same probability density scale. For example one of them goes from 1.0e-05 to 5.0e-6 while the other goes from 1e-5 to 2.5e-5. Ideally I would want them all on the same probability scales.

Comment: In that case you probably misunderstood the purpose of `scale_alpha` in ggplot (which is precisely meant for changing transparency). Perhaps you want to add `limits = c(5.0e-6, 1e-5)` (or whatever the range of values across your heatmaps turn out to be) inside `scale_fill_gradientn()`?